# On Whisper API, when I try to use a python script for transcribing audio files in bulk, I can't get the correct response_format ('srt' or 'vtt') work

Tags: python, syntax-error, srt, webvtt, openai-whisper

I'm using this code for connecting to Whisper API and transcribe in bulk all mp3 in a folder to both srt and vtt:

```
import requests
import os
import openai

folder_path = "/content/audios/"
def transcribe_and_save(file_path, format):
    url = 'https://api.openai.com/v1/audio/transcriptions'
    headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer MyToken'}
    files = {'file': open(file_path, 'rb'), 
            'model': (None, 'whisper-1'),
            'response_format': format}
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, files=files)
    output_path = os.path.join(folder_path, os.path.splitext(filename)[0] + '.' + format)
    with open(output_path, 'w') as f:
        f.write(response.content.decode('utf-8'))

for filename in os.listdir(folder_path):
    if filename.endswith('.mp3'):
        file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, filename)
        transcribe_and_save(file_path, 'srt')
        transcribe_and_save(file_path, 'vtt')
else:
    print('mp3s not found in folder')
```

When I use this code, I'm getting the following error:

```
"error": {
    "message": "1 validation error for Request\nbody -> response_format\n  value is not a valid enumeration member; permitted: 'json', 'text', 'vtt', 'srt', 'verbose_json' (type=type_error.enum; enum_values=[<ResponseFormat.JSON: 'json'>, <ResponseFormat.TEXT: 'text'>, <ResponseFormat.VTT: 'vtt'>, <ResponseFormat.SRT: 'srt'>, <ResponseFormat.VERBOSE_JSON: 'verbose_json'>])",
    "type": "invalid_request_error",
    "param": null,
    "code": null
  }
```

I've tried with different values, but either don't work or I'm only receiving the transcription as a object in plain text, but no srt or vtt. I'm expecting to get srt and vtt files in the same folder as where audios are

Thanks,
Javi

Answer (score 3):

I've found the solution, the problem was in one of the parameters 'response_format': (None, output_format):

```
def transcribe_and_save(file_path, output_format):
    url = 'https://api.openai.com/v1/audio/transcriptions'
    headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer myToken'}
    files = {'file': open(file_path, 'rb'),
             'model': (None, 'whisper-1'),
             'response_format': (None, output_format)}
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, files=files)
    output_path = os.path.join(folder_path, os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(file_path))[0] + '.' + output_format)
    with open(output_path, 'w') as f:
        f.write(response.content.decode('utf-8'))

for filename in os.listdir(folder_path):
    if filename.endswith('.mp3'):
        file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, filename)
        transcribe_and_save(file_path, 'srt')
        transcribe_and_save(file_path, 'vtt')
else:
    print('mp3s not found in folder')
```

Comment: you are a genius, and according to your format.
when you want a english sub from a foreign language ,
just add `'language':(None,'en')` to the `files`.

Comment: Thank you very much!! We're so excited to use this api.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the whisper api, but you seem to be using an already existing python function as a parameter name.
Perhaps this could be a reason why it is not working, as the function `format` is being used when calling the endpoint **instead of the parameter you passed in**.

Try changing the parameter name to something other than format and change the value being used for `response_format`.

Comment: Thanks, Thomasssb1! Yes, you're right. my mistake :). I changed that, but I'm still getting the same error.

if I delete the response_format parameter:
files = {'file': open(file_path, 'rb'),
             'model': (None, 'whisper-1')}
             #'response_format': response_format}
I'm not getting an error, but the object with the transcribed text:
{"text":"This is Stella. She's eight."}
But what I want to have are the srt and vtt format, not just the transcription.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working Solution for single files:

```
import requests
import os

OPENAI_API_KEY = "123xyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyz"

token = f"Bearer {OPENAI_API_KEY}"

url = "https://api.openai.com/v1/audio/transcriptions"
model_name ="whisper-1"

headers ={
    "Authorization": token,
    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
}

file_path ="1.mp3"
with open(file_path,"rb") as file:
    file_content = file.read()

payload = {
    "name": os.path.basename(file_path),
    "response_format": "json",
    "prompt": "transcribe this Chapter",
    "language": "de",
    "model": model_name
}

files = {
    "file": (os.path.basename(file_path), file_content, "audio/mp3")
}

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload, files=files)


print(response.text)
```